# updateOrCreate laravel not working with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I have problem when I use method `updateOrCreate` in SQL Server

Here is my code

```
 McuDiagnosisResult::updateOrCreate([
        [
            'diagnostic_code' => $request->diagnostic_code,
            'no_reg' => trim($request->no_reg)
        ],
        [
            'remarks' => $request->remarks,
            'diagnostic_result' => $request->diagnostic_result,
            'created_by' => trim($user_id),
            'updated_by' => trim($user_id)
        ]
    ]);
```

But when I execute this code it shows an error like this

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'user'. (SQL: select top 1 * from [mcu_diagnosis_results] where ([EKG] = MCU1904010004 user[Kesan EKG] = Diagnosis EKG))

Can help about this problem / have solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])

updateOrCreate have two array parameters, you are passing one array as parameters.

```php
McuDiagnosisResult::updateOrCreate(
        [
            'diagnostic_code' => $request->diagnostic_code,
            'no_reg' => trim($request->no_reg)
        ],
        [
            'remarks' => $request->remarks,
            'diagnostic_result' => $request->diagnostic_result,
            'created_by' => trim($user_id),
            'updated_by' => trim($user_id)
        ]
    );
```

Comment: Hi @TsaiKoga thanks its work

i have wrong write syntax code